# Insert the filenames into the same file using perl or shell

Tags: linux, perl

I have multiple files and I need to put the filenames into the each correspondent file as a new field.

Example:

```
My directory

Sample1.txt Sample3.txt
Sample2.txt Sample4.txt
```

I have into each file
head Sample1.txt

```
 hg1 1 20 
 hg1 40 60
```

I need for each file

```
head Sample1.txt

hg1 1 20 Sample1
hg1 40 60 Sample1
```

I can make it manually, but I have a bunch of files. Could somebody help me make it for all files using a loop?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

for vari in $(ls test?); do
  gawk -v fname=$vari '{print $0 " " fname}' $vari > $vari.bak
  mv -f $vari.bak $vari 
done
```

In the above example, I used test? ; the final answer requires the file name pattern or literally the listing of input files.This works.